# Regex expresion

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the next text

```
aaa ... bbb
ccc ... ddd
eee ... fff
```

But sometimes can be like this.

```
aaa ... bbb
ccc ... ddd
eee
```

They are different lines.
I need to search if there are 3 points in the last line. if so, identify the last word included the 3 points.

I could get the last line with this expression: `/\n.*$/`.

Now I need to find out how to get 3 points within the last line. I know a point is `\.`.

Comment: Im on it. I could get the last line with this expression.
/\n.*$/
Now i need to find out how to get 3 points within the last line. i know a point is '\.'

Comment: Something like https://regex101.com/r/kYblv5/1 but in JavaSript? And what are you going to do with the match? Extract? Replace? Please update the question.

Comment: hi @WiktorStribiżew
that is a good approx. i need to select the 3 points and the rest until the end. it can be a word or more with many characters. i want  to remove everything if there is a match or remove the whole line in javascript but that's not a problem. i can use match and replace.

Comment: So, `text = text.replace(/\r?\n.*\.{3}.*$/, '')`? Please add your current attempt to the question. Explain what output you expect.

Comment: here you are an example of what i am trying to achieve. 
https://regex101.com/r/0A7MsA/3/
thanks

Comment: i want to get everything after the 2 points ( 2 points included) in the last line.

Comment: So, `.replace(/\.{2}.+$/, '')`? See https://regex101.com/r/0A7MsA/4

Comment: that's perfect. Thank a lot  Wiktor!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
text = text.replace(/\.{2}.+$/, '')
```

See the [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/0A7MsA/4).

**Details**

- `\.{2}` - two dots
- `.+` - one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.